# how to manually add tax_percentage and item_total in invoice using zoho api?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, zohobooks

i am use zoho books api.
i am create invoice using below code :-

```
$url = "https://books.zoho.com/api/v3/invoices";
$headers = array(
   "Authorization:" . $zoho_token,
   "Content-Type:  application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
);
$data = array(
          "customer_id" => "my-customer-id",
          "line_items" => array(
             array(
                 "name" => "Test Product",
                 "rate" => 10,
                 "quantity" => 5,
                 "tax_percentage"=>5,
                 "item_total" => 52.5
             ),
          ),
          "date" => date("Y-m-d"),
   );
   $jsonData = "&JSONString=" . urlencode(json_encode($data));
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
   $urlData = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($urlData);
```

Invoice is added but still on my zoho account tax_percentage and item_total not add that show item_total automatically.so tax not added in item_total.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `tax_percentage`, provide `tax_id`. It will work

Comment: i need to give tax for both interstate GST and intrastate GST. So how may i give please if it possible give me a simple example.

Comment: Either by item details api or from default tax preferences api or from taxes api, you can get both the inter and intra tax. Based on the place of supply chosen for invoice, pass the tax in tax_id node.